# How to remove bootable VHD on Windows 10 safely

Tags: windows-10, multi-boot, vhd

On my Windows 10 (ja-jp) machine, I have created a VHD for dual booting (maxiumum=98304 type=expandable).

[Screenshot: Dual Boot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Diy.png)

However, I now want to remove the VHD and re-installl Windows again. I do not know if this is a good or correct site for my situation ([How to remove virtual drives in Windows10](https://windowsreport.com/remove-virtual-drive/)) but I cannot find the VHD in my **Disk Management**.

[Screenshot: Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAmUh.png)

So I right click the VHD (.vhdx file) and try to mount it, but it fails with a **Couldn't Mount File** pop up message of:

> Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file.

(found English equivalent of the Japanese message). However the VHD appears as **Disk 1** in the **Disk Management** as shown in the screenshot right below.

[Screenshot: **Couldn't Mount File** & Updated Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbVUI.png)

Furthermore, before doing all of this, I moved the .vhdx from its original location with a disastrous result. Right after moving it and restarting the computer, I received a "Recovery" with `Error Code: 0xc000000f`. Through F9 of the blue "Recovery" screen:

> Press F9 to use a different operating system

(found English equivalent of the Japanese message), I was able to circumvent `Error Code: 0xc000000f` but maybe the **Couldn't Mount File** is due to this.

[Screenshot: Error Code 0xc000000f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSgPi.jpg)

So I want to know how I can remove a bootable VHD safely from my Windows 10 now.

Comment: Recently I am getting new **Couldn't Mount File** error when mounting. The error message goes like `This disk image isn't initialized, contains partitions that aren't recognizable, or contains volumes that haven't been assigned drive letters. Please use the Disk Management snap-in to make sure that the disk, partitions, and volumes are in a usable state.` (found English equivalent of the Japanese message). Here is screenshot of the error message albeit in Japanese if anyone is interested: [Screenshot: Couldn't Mount File: Disk Image Isn't Initialized ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfRV2.png)

Comment: In order to avoid the [**Couldn't Mount File:** Disk Image Isn't Initialized ...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfRV2.png) error, I assigned a drive letter of ``D:\`` to it. I could now see the content of .vhdx (things like `D:\ProgramData` folder, etc). I now tried deleting the mounted & assigned .vhdx volume through "Disk Management". However that leads to another problem when booting the machine. I again see "Recovery" with [Screenshot: Error Code 0xc0000225](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NBtz.png) error. I pressed "F9" again to circumvent the error. So this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove the bootable VHD on Windows 10, follow these steps:

1. Press **Win+R** on the keyboard and type `msconfig` into the **Run** box.
2. From the popped up **System Configuration**, select **Boot** tab.
3. Carefully **select** the boot entry that you want to delete
   ([Screenshot: Example Selection of Boot Entry to Delete [ja-jp]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H65O8.png)).
4. Press **Delete** button.
5. Press **Apply** button.
6. Press **OK** button.
7. Press **Restart** button if you want to restart the machine.
   Otherwise press the other button.
8. After restarting, you can do whatever you want with the .vhdx file.

Atleast, this worked for me. Perhaps the fact that it was not assgined a drive letter was to blame (as shown in the selected entry of [Screenshot: Example Selection of Boot Entry to Delete [ja-jp]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H65O8.png)). I have no idea now since it is now resolved.

Here is the title of this issue in Japanese so that someone who search in Japanese may visit this page: *VHD を使って DualBoot (デュアルブート) を実現した際の Window 10 における VHD の安全な削除の仕方*

Comment: PS: This site helped me resolve the problem [**Delete Boot Menu Entry in Windows 10**](https://winaero.com/delete-boot-menu-entry-in-windows-10/) -> **Delete Windows 10 Boot Menu Entry with msconfig.exe** section